# How to import from another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

very good day!

I come to you for help.

I'm new to learning Python with an Udemy course.

Within this course a basic project must be done under console, the problem I have is the following:
According to the attached image, in the left panel you can see the project structure (yellow box). Inside this I have the "models" directory where 3 methods are located.

Inside the method "users.py" I need to import the method located inside "db_pro", but Visual Studio Code marks me as an error that I cannot find it.

I have tried several ways without success, I really appreciate your collaboration to be able to carry out this import correctly.

[image: I attach the project]

Thank you so much

Comment: I'm calling db_pro.py file from users.py

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: `models.db_pro` is a folder. Did you mean `from models.db_pro.db_pro import *`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes I'm doing this: from proyecto1.models.db_pro import db_pro

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does your code *actually* work when you run it? Because it looks like just a pylint error. Sometimes pylint show import-error when it can't find modules from custom file/folder structure, but your code actually runs.

Answer (score 1):

As KJDII mentioned. Try adding **init**.py file in Your modules folder.
What it does is tell python interpreter, that this specific folder should be treated as python package.
**init**.py file may be left empty.

If this want help, read about attaching packages to python's PATH. Pyhon have it's specific path of searching for packages to be imported.

EDIT:
As I wrote above. Python searches in specific path for packages. Your import is more complex than having a single module file and main app file in exact same folder. Thus python interpreter does not see Your module in its PATH (this topic is more complex, but I encourage You to read about it). What You need to do is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(absolute_path_to_your_module)
import your_module_name
```

What this will do is every time You run app, sys.path.append adds this moduke_path to PATH environment variable.
Absolute path means, it needs full path from home up to your models directory. Example path: '/home/desktop/my_project/modules'
After this You will gain access to modules directory and just

```
import db_pro
```

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work

Comment: If You added  __init__.py, please provide again only Yours file tree and line of code with import